# How to update ListView from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, database, listview, android-asynctask

I am loading images by using **AsyncTask** and for updating ListView I am using **notifyDataSetChanged()** method.

But **notifyDataSetChanged()** doesn't change anything in the ListView onProgressUpdate().
I don't want to use **cursor.requery** because it is deprecated method.

Why **notifyDataSetChanged()** is not working for me?

```
public class News extends BasicActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private ListView lvNews;
private TaskImgSm taskImgSm = null;
private NewsListAdapter adapter;
private Cursor cur;
boolean pause = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news);

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(((MyApp) getApplication()).getDbPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    lvNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_news);
    lvNews.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listFilling();

    if (taskImgSm != null && taskImgSm.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) taskImgSm.cancel(true);
    taskImgSm = new TaskImgSm();
    taskImgSm.execute();        
}

private void listFilling() {
    cur = db.query("news", new String[] { "_id", "id_news", "title", "date", "img_url", "img_sm" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    adapter = new NewsListAdapter(this, cur, db);
    lvNews.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class TaskImgSm extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    Cursor curs;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        curs = db.query("news", new String[] { "_id", "id_news", "img_url", "img_sm" }, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(curs);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        curs.moveToFirst();
        while (curs.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if (curs.getBlob(curs.getColumnIndex("img_sm")) == null) {
                String imgUrl = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("img_url"));
                String idNews = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("id_news"));
                updateImg(imgUrl, idNews, "img_sm");
                publishProgress();
            }
            curs.moveToNext();
        }           
        return (null);
    }

    private void updateImg(String img_URL, String whereId, String imgColumn) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet();
            mHttpGet.setURI(new URI(img_URL));
            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    // insert to database
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(imgColumn, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
                    db.update("news", values, "id_news=" + whereId, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
        if (pause == false) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    pause = true;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    pause = false;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (taskImgSm != null && taskImgSm.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) taskImgSm.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: 1. don't store images in DB 2. use Ihttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Comment: Why does I must not to use DB for storing images? As I know it is working enough quickly in comparison with file system.

Comment: your db will grow unnecessary ... good practice on android in such cases is to store only a path(on android filesystem(cache/external/internal storage)) to file in db... anyway ... is your db static(distrbuted with apk) or you download it ?

Comment: why don't you put images to drawable folder and use overriden SimpleCursorAdapter with method `@Override public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) { Context ctx = v.getContext(); v.setImageResource(ctx .getResources().getIdentifier(value, "drawable", ctx .getPackageName())); }` and in db just store name of this drawable ?

Comment: It's not a problem to store images in folder/db/sd/drawable. I want simply to update **ListView** after that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5059/discussion-between-selvin-and-svyatoslav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use a ContentProvider.

With a ContentProvider you can update your table with the notifyChange(uri) method

Tutorial for that here http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because `notifyDataSetChanged()` only tells the ListView that the data *in the adapter* has changed. Since that data hasn't changed (because you haven't queried the database again), then the ListView won't show any updates. You need to execute the query again and update the data in the adapter, *then* call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the data in the adapter"? What does I must to write in **onProgressUpdate** method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to update the `ImageView` in a `ListView` in the `onPostExecute()` method.  This is how I accomplished something similar to what you are doing : [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)